# Can a type be accessed like a dictionary directly without using a static member?

Tags: c#, dictionary, static

This could be a flawed design pattern, but I thought I would ask to be sure I am doing it the only way possible.

This works:

```cs
public static class StuffManager
{
    public static readonly StuffDict Stuff = new StuffDict();
}

public class StuffDict : IDictionary<string, string>
{
    // custom dictionary stuff
}
```

Here a user has to type:

```cs
string athing = StuffManager.Stuff["key"]
```

.

This is what I am wondering about....

```cs
public static class StuffManager : IDictionary<string, string>
{
    // custom dictionary stuff
}
```

If this worked, a user would instead type:

```cs
string athing = StuffManager["key"]
```

I'm fine if the answer is "no" I just want confirmation that the second pattern is either not possible or a bad idea. If it is relevant, this is for use as a sort-of plugin in a 3rd party application where a user would add my .cs files than be a user from inside the same application.

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to add a tag for what language this question is about..

Comment: Looks a bit like C#, but the OP should confirm.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, edited, this was my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

It doesn't make sense for a static class to inherit from a non-static class. Any inherited instance members would still be instance members, and couldn't be used from the static class.